# selenium c# edge browser : 'Unexpected error. Unknown error'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, windows-10, microsoft-edge

OS Build Number:- 18363.900
Edge Version: 83.0.478.54
MicrosoftWebDriver Version: 83.0.478.54

Here is the code:

```
  System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.edge.driver", "E:\\edgedriver_win64\\msedgedriver.exe");
  IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
```

I am getting error as: **OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Unexpected error. Unknown error'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Selenium WebDriver are you using? I suggest you to use the latest version [4.0.0-alpha05](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/4.0.0-alpha05) and use the code below:

```
EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
edgeOptions.UseChromium = true;
edgeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
var msedgedriverDir = @"D:\webdriver83.0.478.54";
var driver = new EdgeDriver(msedgedriverDir, edgeOptions);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://bing.com");
Thread.Sleep(3000);
driver.Close();
```

**Note:** **Change the paths in the code to your owns.**

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am using selenium 3.141.0 in NuGet Package Manager.  I am not able to find the version  "4.0.0-alpha05" NuGet Package Manager. Could you share the steps to get the latest version

Comment: You could run `Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver -Version 4.0.0-alpha05` in Package Manager Console to install it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/erupP.png. To open the Package Manager Console window, you could click **View-> Other Windows-> Package Manager Console**.